# Launch activity outside of activity class

Tags: java, android

I have activity class called "MainActivity" and I'm trying to launch a different activity from outside of the MainActivity class. I tried this:

```java
MainActivity mainActivityInstance = new MainActivity();
Intent launchPublicChat = new Intent(mainActivityInstance, PublicChat.class);
mainActivityInstance.startActivity(launchPublicChat);
```

It throws this error when I try:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Thread-3,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Answer (score 2):

You NEVER call new on an Activity class.  You call context.startActivity() and the framework calls new for you.  If you don't have a Context where you need it, pass it in somehow as a parameter.  But you cannot new an activity instance and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Gabe's spot-on answer, this is how you go about with the code:

```
 //create a new intent passing in the context and the 2nd activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PublicChat.class);
        
        //launching the second activity
        startActivity(intent);
```